# Draggable, droppable and sortable at same time

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable, resizable

Here I have some example: http://jsfiddle.net/mfkDz/ and I want to know how to make it:

```
#thing > draggable, resizable, sortable on #row ?
#div1 > droppable for #photo ?
#row > droppable and sortable horizontally for #thing 
#photo > draggable to #div1 but also when drag there to change css like #thing
```

and jquery UI code:

```
$('#thing').draggable();
$('#thing').resizable();
$('#thing').sortable();

$('#row').droppable ({
    accept:('#thing');
    //how to make it sortable horizontally?
});

$('#photo').draggable();
$('#div1').droppable({
    accept:('#photo');
    //how to make it sortable vertically?
    //how to make when accept #photo to change ID to #thing and make it sortable there
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mfkDz/1/

Comment: first of all it is not going to work with more than 1 id having the same name. second, there are loads of errors in your fiddle, please rectify them.